# Knockout View Model Reset -- When Observables Require Defaults

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Let us say that I have the following simplified and generic view model, which uses KnockoutJS and the [Knockout Validation library](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to create/manipulate and validate observables, respectively.

```
// view declared

// KnockoutJS loaded
// KnockoutValidation loaded

var ChildNodePropertiesVM = function(properties) {
    var self = this;

    /* data within properties object are assigned to
       observables within VM */
};

var ChildNode = function() {
    var self = this;
    var options = // data from ajax request sent to web service

    // list of POJOs
    this.availableParentNodes = ko.observableArray();

    // a specific POJO from the list above, selected from an HTML select element
    // Knockout Validation ensures that a value is present (required)
    this.associatedParentNode = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            params: true,
            message: "Please choose a parent"
        }
    });

    // a view model, declared above, constructed with value from options
    this.childProperties = new ChildNodePropertiesVM(options.childProps);

    /* Many more model-members follow, and may be any of the above types
       (observable, observableArray, view model, etc) */
};

// apply bindings to view here (in this case, ko.applyBindingsWithValidation)
```

What I am interested in is, if I want to create a "reset" procedure to clear a majority of the members of a view model (of which there may be many), and keep a minority of the fields as they were, what is the most maintainable way in which I could do so? To be more specific, consider the `availableParentNodes` object to be one of the observables that I would like to keep, while `associatedParentNode` must be cleared (as in, `self.associatedParentNode(undefined)`), and half of the (undeclared) model-members of `childProperties` must be set to null, as part of the reset process.

SO and search engine queries either suggest that each observable/variable be cleared manually, or that a new view model (in this case, the `ChildNode` view model) simply be created to replace the old one. Since I have specific fields that I would like to keep, the latter is not an option, and since there are so many observables in these models, the former is unmaintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option would be to create a generic reset function, with a whitelist parameter for the observables you would like to keep. Here's an example (polyfill `indexOf` if you need to support outdated browsers):

```
var reset = function ( obj, whitelist ) {
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) && ko.isObservable( obj[ prop ] ) && whitelist.indexOf( prop ) === -1 ) {
            obj[ prop ]( undefined );
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can curry this function with your whitelist on your individual models.

```
SomeModel.prototype.reset = function () {
    reset( this, [ 'something', 'somethingElse' ] );
};
```

The above would set every observable except the ones named `something` and `somethingElse` in your model to `undefined`.

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wedvich/Lso3fde5/1/).

Comment: Perfect -- maintainable and concise.

Answer (score 0):

this could be done in a simple way by creating a function

```
self.Reset = function(){
    self.someobservable(null)
    self.someobservbleArray([])
}
```

And now simply call it

```
self.Reset()
```

The values will be reset.

Comment: Hmmm, well, as I say in my last paragraph, clearing each observable/variable manually does not seem like a very maintainable solution. In reality, my view model has about 30 observables/view models in it!